# Paging with optional parameters LARAVEL 4

Tags: parameters, laravel-4, pagination

I am listing records and paging is all good, but when I pass optional parameters such as:

/panelapp/usuarios?nivel=admin&page=2

I only recognize the variable page ignores the other and does the filter, as it might do? I leave here the code:

Route:

```
Route::get('/panelapp/usuarios', array(
'as'    =>  'panel-lista-usuarios',
'uses'  =>  'CuentaController@getLista'
));
```

CuentaController:

```
public function getLista(){
    $lista = Usuario::paginate(10);
    return View::make('panelapp.cuentas.lista')->with('usuarios',$lista);  
}
```

View:

```
@foreach($usuarios->getCollection()->all() as $item)
{{ mostrando items... }}
@endforeach
{{ $usuarios->appends(Request::except('page'))->links() }}
```

Comment: You need to post this in english.

Comment: sorry, I edited my question

Comment: From your code I see you're not using the `nivel` parameter, why you assume it's getting ignored?

Comment: `$lista = Usuario::where('nivel', Input::get('nivel'))->paginate(10);`

This would help me so that the filter is static, but what I need is that the level parameter is optional and the pagination is Realize according to Parameters received for url: 
for instance:
 
case: 1 
/panelapp/users?level=admin&page=2 


case 2 
/panelapp/users?level=admin&status=1&page = 2 


case 3 
/panelapp/users?level=admin&status=1&order=desc&page=2 

case: n ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going with a blind shot here but I think what you need is:

```
public function getLista()
{
    $nivel = Input::get('nivel', default_level);
    $status = Input::get('status', default_status);
    $order = Input::get('order', default_order);
    // ... you get the idea

    $lista = Usuario::where('nivel', $nivel)
                    ->where('status', $status)
                    ->where('order', $order)
                    ->paginate(10);

    return View::make('panelapp.cuentas.lista')->with('usuarios',$lista);  
}
```

Where `default_level`, `default_status` and `default_order` are your default values.

Comment: ok, I understand the idea, but I do not want to put a paramatro value by default, what I need is that I recognize whether the parameter does not exist, according to that the query is executed, that at first the url will be as follows:/panelapp/usuarios

Comment: Then set the default as `null` and check `if ($nivel)`. Do the same with the others and run your queries according to your `if`s.

Comment: Ok the code works perfectly, thank you all for your support, they are great here